# Why Custom Group behaves differently in a Simulation Zone and in a normal chain of nodes? [Bug fixed in 4.0α]

Tags: node-editor, geometry-nodes, error, simulation-nodes

Consider this Custom Group:

[image]

It adds a line segment to existing path of the "Lazer", by raycasting towards a default geonode cube using provided position, direction and index of a face to ignore. Then it passes the information needed for the next line segment. Since there's no recursion in Geonodes, a setup like this has to be chained like so:

[image]

(the Cube visible in wireframe mode has been added outside this setup)

So if the above works, why doesn't the below?

[image]

Apparently, it works for the first evaluation, but then fails. I have done some more investigation, but haven't yet gained a full, satisfactory explanation, and I don't want to suggest a potentially wrong answer, so here it goes, do you know what's going on?

> Is this the real bug? Is this just design?

[image]

A workaround is easy (and this could be a part of an answer…):

[image]

But the question is why the workaround is even needed, what's the logic (and fully understanding the logic might result in a better solution).

Comment: Maybe a good fit for another question, but while I test various workarounds, I find myself in this situation: https://i.imgur.com/nP8i0eC.png - how could possibly the 0 or 1, plus 2, become less than 2?

Comment: Most likely it was a recently fixed bug, can you check in new versions?

Comment: @modnop the above was originally tested on stable 3.6 from 27 jun, which version do you have in mind? Is there a newer 3.6 or do you mean 4.0? There's a .blend file link in the question btw.

Comment: Yes, 4.0. Example file also work correct in today 4.0.

Comment: @modnop thanks for your input, I'll observe this until B4.0 goes to β, I thought this is a bug at first (but as you noticed on Discord, sometimes I'm wrong on that), and then thought maybe it's about the geometry already existing in a custom group chain (which is evaluated from right to left), but not yet existing for a given frame (frames are evaluated from beginning to an end). However no explanation would fit my prior understanding on geonodes evaluation (here the constant outputs shouldn't be dependant on future geometry…). I confirm currently it works as expected (is fixed) in 4.0α

Comment: Then it's a duplicate of https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/issues/109341

Answer (score 1):

Feels like a design for me TBH, but i am not completely sure.
I would just create a named attribute and update it with every step, than use than named attribute as an input inside a node group, so you do not have to pass it inside a simulation zone